# GLONASS speed and altitude limitations

Tags: gps, altitude, limitations

I'm looking for some info about the possible limitations for the GLONASS navigation system, something similar to the GPS COCOM limits. 
Is there any limitation on speed AND/OR altitude for this navigation system?

We are looking into embedding a GLONASS receiver into an high-altitude balloon project.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Could you link to, or better yet link to and describe, the GPS COCOM limits? Some background will help.

Comment: Related question for GPS [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19811/gps-module-without-velocity-or-altitude-limitations)

Comment: Might want to search on the word 'restrict' in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS). It talks about how the signals are limited and the security used in accuracy correction. I suspect that country of origin/use is going to play a role. As mentioned at the linked question, who can export what to where at what capability level is going to vary. For instance you can get certain radio scanners in the UK that violate US laws and regulations. Since GLONASS is Russian, units available there may not be subject to the same restrictions as those in the US (ie, opposite of GPS).

Comment: @Simbamangu [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoCom#Legacy) is the Wiki article about COCOm limits for GPS. I've already read the GPS article, but could not find any info about GLONASS specific limitations.